# Logout PHP sessions - update only last record

Tags: php, session, logout

I'm doing a new program about attendence with PHP and JS. I create a Login by username/pw. I'm working with sessions.
I want put logout and do it hours worked (I know do difference between hours, using datediff.

But when I update time logout, **It does update to ALL results** but I want update only last record this person.. and not all results this person (session).

```
$sql = "UPDATE `login` SET `datelogout` = NOW() WHERE `uid` = '$session_id' ";
```

[image: image on what is doing wrong]

I just wanna update record logout by day and by session login this day!

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what the real problem is here. And while you might be sure that the problem is related to the SQL, you probably need to present some code for context here. You should rework this question to show what you have, what you have done, and the results you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
UPDATE  login SET datelogout=NOW() where uid ='$sessionid' orderby Sno DESC 
LIMIT 1
```